# How to use Fill-Up in SSIS just like Fill-Up function in Power BI

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Here is the sample data which I want to Fill Up:

[Here is the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADEQN.png)

I use this code in script component but it fill down the data as i want fill up:

```
private string LastValue = ""
 
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        if (Row.Category_IsNull == true)
        {
            Row.Category = LastValue;
        }
        else
        {
            LastValue = Row.Category;
        }

    }
```

Comment: SSIS has no simple function to do this. You could write a script transformation to do it but I can't find an example right now. Are you familiar with C#?

Comment: I write this code in script transformation but this code fill down the values but i want to fill up function here is the code:


private string LastValue = "";
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        
        if (Row.Category_IsNull == true)
        {
            Row.Category = LastValue;
        }
        else
        {
            LastValue = Row.Category;
        }

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the link with some text samples, and also include your above code. I guess to fill up instead of down you need to feed your data in in the reverse order right?

Comment: i was thinking how to reverse the data stream. Maybe add a row number (kind of like an identity) and then sort descending and then apply your code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes want to fill up the data from bottom to top.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment _I guess to fill up instead of down you need to feed your data in in the reverse order_

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried this but its not woking

Comment: "not working" doesn't mean anything. I don't think I can help any further.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a rownumber using the logic here... https://richardswinbank.net/ssis/adding_row_numbers_to_ssis_dataflows
2. Sort RowNumber descending
3. Use your code to fill.

Comment: I have to assume your data is not all data and that it would end with a value and not null.